# getting Traceback (most recent call last): main() NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Tags: python

```
from letprob import *

class Cipher(object):
    def __init__(self, inputString):
        self.inputString = inputString
        self.encodedString = ''
        self.decodedString = ''

    def __repr__(self):
        s = 'Original String: %s\nEncoded String: %s\nDecoded String: %s' \
        % (self.inputString, self.encodedString, self.decodedString)
        return s
  
    def encipher(self, n):

        for i in (self.inputString):


            if 'a' <= i <= 'z':
                encWord = (ord(i) + n - 97) % 26 + 97
                encWord1 = chr(encWord)
                self.encodedString += encWord1


            elif 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
                newWord = (ord(i) + n - 65) % 26 + 65
                newWord1 = chr(newWord)
                self.encodedString += newWord1

            else:
                 self.encodedString += i
  

    def decipherEasy(self, n):

        for i in (self.encodedString):


            if 'a' <= i <= 'z':
                decWord = (ord(i) - n - 97) % 26 + 97
                decWord1 = chr(decWord)
                self.decodedString += decWord1


            elif 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
                newWordD = (ord(i) - n - 65) % 26 + 65
                newWord1D = chr(newWordD)
                self.decodedString += newWord1D

            else:
                self.decodedString += i




    def shift(self, encodedString, n):
        decodedString = ''
        for i in (encodedString):


            if 'a' <= i <= 'z':
                decWord = (ord(i) + n - 97) % 26 + 97
                decWord1 = chr(decWord)
                decodedString += decWord1


            elif 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
                newWordD = (ord(i) + n - 65) % 26 + 65
                newWord1D = chr(newWordD)
                decodedString += newWord1D

            else:
                decodedString += i
                return decodedString


    def decipher(self):
        shiftList = []
        score = 0

        for i in range(0, 26+1):
            shiftStr = self.shift(self.encodedString, i)
            prob = self.possibleProb(shiftStr)
            shiftList.append([shiftStr, prob])

            self.sortProb(shiftList)

#print(shiftList)
#return shiftList


    def sortProb(self, List):
        size = len(self.shiftList)

        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(1, size):
                if List[j][1] > List[j - 1][1]:
                    print(j)
                    temp = List[j]
                    List[j] = List[j - 1]
                    List[j-1] = temp

                else:
                    return List
  

    def possibleProb(self, sentence):

        s = 0

        for i in sentence:
            s += letProb(i)
            return s


    def main():
        cipher = Cipher('this')
        cipher.encipher(1)
# cipher.decipherEasy(1)
        cipher.decipher()
        print(cipher)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    main()
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

Will someone help me functioning this code?
have tried everything nothing worked
unable to run the program it shows this error?

Comment: `main` is indented, making it a method of the class, not its own function. Dedent.

Comment: As a general debug technique, make a copy of your program and mercilessly chop away everything not associated with the bug. The smallest program possible with the bug often shows you what is wrong. In this case, you can't call main so 99% of the code is never run and is not needed for an example.

Comment: when i de-indent it says main() ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: It worked for me. Which line gets that error? Its the line that calls `main()` at the bottom?

Comment: Oh, right. You need to dedent the `def main():` function and its content. Not the call `main()`.

Comment: showing this error now,  or i in sentence:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: That's a different bug and worth a different question that includes your fixed code and the full traceback that shows the compete call stack. But just scanning the code, it looks like `shift()` returns `None` in the `if` and `elif` cases. You may want to sprinkle some prints around the code or step through in a debugger to work through these details.

Comment: Consider writing unit tests for this code. If you have tests focused on the `shift` operation, you can debug it before it messes up another method.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging this type of problem, it helps to remove everything that is not related and get down to the smallest program that still produces the same error. Since the program crashes almost immediately, almost everything can go. This script produces the same error

```
class Cipher(object):
    def main():
        print("not fubar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the problem is easy to spot: `main` should not be part of the class.

```
class Cipher(object):
    pass

def main():
    print("not fubar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Apply that fix to the real program and you are on to the next issue.